# AWS cron jobs to run every minute across a span of time across two hours?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I have a Lambda function on AWS scheduled using the following cron expression:

`* 19-20 ? * SAT *`

So it runs every minute from 19:00 - 20:59 on Saturdays. In reality, though, it really just needs to run from 19:50 - 20:30 on Saturdays, and my current setup is costing me money for no good reason. Is there any way to specify that with a cron expression (or is there another AWS scheduling mechanism I could use to accomplish this)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to split it to two expressions:

From 19:50-19:59:

```
50/1 19 ? * SAT *
```

From 20:00-20:30:

```
0-30/1 20 ? * SAT *
```

Comment: So I guess in AWS-land that means two separate triggers, right?

Comment: @CollinBell Yes, two CloudWatch rules.

Comment: @CollinBell No problem. Glad could help.

Comment: @Marcin would 50/1 19,20 ? * SAT * work?